# perform aggregate computation on Github data

Tags: rest, statistics, graphql, analytics, github-api

I have a Github (Enterprise) organization with multiple repositories. Each repository contains one or more `.properties` files.
Some of these `.properties` files will be contained in folders that contain "i18n" in their path or filename.
These `.properties` files would be relevant for translation processes.

As a basic step: I would need to get the average/min/max frequency of commits that involve translation-relevant files (as defined above) for each one of the repositories.

As an ideal scenario: I would also need to determine how many key-values were changed/added/deleted by each commit on average, to better determine the resulting workload for the translation process.

What I tried so far:

- Github GraphQL APIs v4: seems to me that the API is very well suited for searching, but not as much for computing aggregations.
- Github ReST APIs v3: specific commits can be searched, but not based on file extension. While file extensions are a query criteria for files themselves, they are not for commits.

Any hint on how to achieve this?